# EOFError: EOF when reading a line, is there another way for me to write this code to prevent this?

Tags: python

```py
import math 
    
r=input("Please enter the radius") 
h=input("Please enter the height")
    
def cone_area(r,h): 
    while True:
        try:
            r,h = float(r),float(h)
            break
        except ValueError:
            return 'Error not a number' 
    a=((math.pi*r*(r+math.sqrt(r*r+h*h)))) #  surface area formula
    return round(a,4)
    
print(cone_area(r,h))
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Please enter the radius ↩
Error ↩
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 3, in <module>
    r=input("Please enter the radius") #asks user for radius and height
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

For clarification, it works fine using python idle but I have to submit this for work into an online python interpreter which is where I get the error message. Another user also confirmed they could replicate this on linux. Where did I go wrong in my code?

Comment: So, all you want to do is ignoring newline character, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try` `except` to solve this problem

```py
try:
  print(input())
except EOFError:
  exit()
```

Extra:
the `while True:` can be removed to increase efficient a bit.

Full code:

```
import math 
def cone_area(r,h):
    try:
        r,h = float(r),float(h)
    except ValueError:
        return 'Error not a number' 
    a=((math.pi*r*(r+math.sqrt(r*r+h*h)))) #  surface area formula
    return round(a,4)

try:
  while True: #infinity amount of input until EOF

    r=input("Please enter the radius") 
    h=input("Please enter the height")
    print(cone_area(r,h))
except EOFError:
  print("input finish")
```